# Record Orbbec Astra streams with python and OpenNI2

Tags: python, openni, orbbec

I'm trying to record depth and color stream form Astra model with this code. It is basically working but there is an issue, after a successfull recording, the next one will not record the depth stream, without any error or exception unless you unplug and reconnect the usb cable. This lead me to think that the final instructions of the method write_files are not working correctly and somehow something is not closed properly (streams, recorder, device.. ). I tried different combinations of close and stop without any luck. Behavior is the same both on Ubuntu 16.04 and Win10, using the latest OpenNI2 package provided by Orbbec. Camera is Astra. Any help?

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import argparse
import sys
import configparser

from openni import openni2
from openni import _openni2 as c_api

width = 640
height = 480
fps = 30
mirroring = True
compression = False
lenght = 300 #5 minutes


def write_files(dev):

    depth_stream = dev.create_depth_stream()
    color_stream = dev.create_color_stream()

    depth_stream.set_video_mode(c_api.OniVideoMode(pixelFormat=c_api.OniPixelFormat.ONI_PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM,
                                                   resolutionX=width,
                                                   resolutionY=height,
                                                   fps=fps))
    color_stream.set_video_mode(c_api.OniVideoMode(pixelFormat=c_api.OniPixelFormat.ONI_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB888,
                                                   resolutionX=width,
                                                   resolutionY=height,
                                                   fps=fps))
    depth_stream.start()
    color_stream.start()
    dev.set_image_registration_mode(True)
    dev.set_depth_color_sync_enabled(True)

    depth_stream.set_mirroring_enabled(mirroring)
    color_stream.set_mirroring_enabled(mirroring)

    actual_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%f")[:-3]
    rec = openni2.Recorder((actual_date + ".oni").encode('utf-8'))
    rec.attach(depth_stream, compression)
    rec.attach(color_stream, compression)
    rec.start()
    print("Recording started.. press ctrl+C to stop or wait " + str(lenght) + " seconds..")
    start=time.time()
    try:
        while True:
            if (time.time()-start)>lenght:
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    rec.stop()
    depth_stream.close()
    color_stream.close()
    dev.close()
    rec.close()
def readSettings():
    global width,height,fps,mirroring,compression,lenght
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('settings.ini')
    width = int(config['camera']['width'])
    height = int(config['camera']['height'])
    fps = int(config['camera']['fps'])
    mirroring = config.getboolean('camera','mirroring')
    compression = config.getboolean('camera','compression')
    lenght = int(config['camera']['lenght'])

def main():

    readSettings()

    try:
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            libpath = "lib/Windows"
        else:
            libpath = "lib/Linux"
        openni2.initialize(libpath)
        print("Device initialized")
    except:
        print("Device not initialized")
        return
    try:
        dev = openni2.Device.open_any()
        write_files(dev)
    except:
        print("Unable to open the device")
    try:
        openni2.unload()
        print("Device unloaded")
    except:
        print("Device not unloaded")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution for this..

Just move these instructions

```
dev.set_image_registration_mode(True)
dev.set_depth_color_sync_enabled(True)
```

before the streams start and will work as expected.